# Post Request: Sending values through arrays in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have to send post request of some values from Mongoose. My model file is as below:

```
const local_lr_urllog_schema = new Schema(
    {       
        domain_name:{
           type: String
        },

        comment:{
            type: String
        },
        local_parameters:[
            {
                source_url: String,
                abstract:String,
                non_abstract: String   
            }
    ],


    }
);

//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Addlogurl', local_lr_urllog_schema);
```

My controller is as below:

```
const add_records = async (req, res) => {


     const records = new Addlogurl({

        domain_name:req.body.domain_name,

        comment:req.body.comment,
        local_parameters:[{source_url: req.body.source_url, abstract: req.body.abstract}]
  });




  try {
    await records.save();
  } catch (err) {

    return next(errors);
  } //res.status(messages.status.OK).json(list);
  res.status(messages.status.OK).json({records: records.toObject({ getters: true })});

  };
```

So my postman throws id values for source_url and abstract.

[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIGU7.png)

Cant get where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is right in the construction of new mongoose object only. Here you refer **source_url** and **abstract** as *req.body.source_url* and *req.body.abstract*, which is wrong because those doesn't come directly under the main level of the object of your request, but only under 1st array element of local_parameters. Changing that should help. The problem here is those values come off as undefined and undefined values are removed by mongoose.

```
const records = new Addlogurl({
  domain_name: req.body.domain_name,

  comment: req.body.comment,
  local_parameters: [
    { source_url: req.body.local_parameters[0].source_url, abstract: req.body.local_parameters[0].abstract }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Can you suggest how should i write it?

Comment: @SimonTufel Added it. But then again in my opinion, it would be good to do a validation on req.body and then pass it on as such into Addlogurl(), instead of doing it manually like this.

Comment: what if I have another sub array.. ``` local_parameters: [
    { source_url: req.body.local_parameters[0].source_url, abstract: req.body.local_parameters[0].abstract }
  ], remote_parameters: [
    { destination_url: req.body.local_parameters[0].destination_url, abstract_des: req.body.local_parameters[0].abstract_des}
  ]. This does not work

Comment: @SimonTufel Yes, the inherent problem with how you have written the base code is you are referring parameters one by one, so instead what you could do is pass remove unnecessary parameters(like remote_parameters) from the req.body object and then pass the validated object to `new Addlogurl()`

Answer (score 0):

what if I have another sub array..

```
local_parameters: [ { source_url: req.body.local_parameters[0].source_url, abstract: req.body.local_parameters[0].abstract } ], 

remote_parameters: [ { destination_url: req.body.local_parameters[0].destination_url, abstract_des: req.body.local_parameters[0].abstract_des} ].
```

This does not work when i send a request for remote_parameters